# Can てしまう mean 'end up' with a positive connotation?

Tags: nuances, english-to-japanese

While てしまう is how you say 'end up' when it's something regrettable, Can you also use it to say 'end up' if it's something good and unexpected such as:

> I ended up making friends with everyone at the party

> パーティーの皆に友達を作ってしまいました。

> I ended up inventing a new recipe

> 新しいレシピを発明してしまいました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most websites (e.g., [this](https://www.tomojuku.com/blog/teshimau/)) seem to explain てしまう mean  **完了** or 後悔. So it can be used for something positive as well, and if *end up* has the connotation of regrettable results, it may not fit.

- 新しいレシピを発明してしまいました。

is natural. This may be a surprise, *you know what, I invented a new recipe!*.  It could be also more simply perfect, implying *finally...*

For the first sentence, a more valid translation would be

- パーティーで全員と友達になってしまいました。

This implies positive surprise, as you wrote.

---

(し)ちゃった as a colloquial variant can be used in the same way as well. I believe in [Tonari no totoro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Neighbor_Totoro) somehere there was a phrase トトロに会っちゃった.

Similarly 発明しちゃいました・しちゃった or 友達になっちゃいました・なっちゃった is ok above.